# Creating Lookup on field on access through query

Tags: ms-access, ms-office, lookup

I am Access novice here.And currently enhancing a database application which is deployed on multiple machines. I am writing scripts(Access queries) to modify the tables. Which works perfectly fine. What I need to know is how to create a lookup on fields through query instead of the wizard.

For instance, I want to associate the language in options only available in Language table. It works if you do it manually, but I want to add the field and the lookup with a script.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unclear and not reproducible.

Comment: @nicomp Adding a new field in a table with Access Alter table query. I want a query to create a look up relation of that field with another table(foreign key)

Comment: I still don't understand what you want. I can do queries and lookups and foreign keys I just don't know your schema and your desired results. If you want help you have to put more effort into your question.

Comment: Ok, So there are two tables, User and Language. I am extending the User table with language. Where users will select the language from a drop down which is populated with records from Language Table. Using the ALTER TABLE User ADD COLUMN Language TEXT(255) I added the field. Since the application needs to run on multiple machines I am trying to create the lookup with a query too, instead of running the wizard. Hope it clear things what I need to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "Create the lookup with a query"  ? Do you have a form with a query as the data source? Do you have controls that populate with a query?  Who is using this query/lookup and how is it being used?

Comment: There is no query, Just a simple lookup with a table, instead of using wizard I want to automate the process. for other things you can write SQL like queries in access. Was wondering if anything like that is present for lookup creation too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146896/discussion-between-nicomp-and-babar).

Comment: I NEVER build lookups in tables, especially lookups with alias. I want to see actual values in table. I build comboboxes on forms. http://access.mvps.org/Access/lookupfields.htm. However, if you must have lookup in table, I don't think can do this with ALTER TABLE. Would need VBA using TableDefs collection to modify table properties.

Comment: Why would you need to programmatically modify tables? IMHO, implementing code that routinely modifies db design is not really a good practice. Tells me db structure is likely not normalized or otherwise not optimized.

Comment: @June7, As mentioned it's not a regular modifying routine, it's an update for an application that is hosted on multiple machines(so a one-time thing). Hence the reason for automation.